# Can't add values to an array on a Bean constructor

Tags: java, list, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

Im trying to add values to an array on the constructor of a ManagedBean, but i'm gettint error.

What im trying is

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EquipamentoBean {

    private List<Equipamento> equipamentos;

    private List<Equipamento> equipamentosFiltrados;

    private List<EquipamentoTipo> tipos;

    public EquipamentoBean(){
        this.equipamentos = new EquipamentoDao().listaEquipamentos();
        for (Equipamento equipamento : equipamentos) {
            this.tipos.add(equipamento.getEquipamentoTipoId());
        }
//      this.tipos = new EquipamentoTipoDao().listaTipos(); WORKS, BUT NEEDS ANOTHER MYSQL CONNECTION
    }
```

Inside my class Equipamento i have an EquipamentoTipo, so each Equipamento is associated to one EquipamentoTipo a 1-N relation.
I need to use the EquipamentoTipo as a filter on the datatable im showing, so instead of making another connection to the dabatase and retrieving all the EquipamentoTipo i just decided do create a list of EquipamentoTipo and fill it using the equipamentos list i already have.

I don't understand why i can fill my List whit a method from another class, but cant fill it whit another List.

**My xhtml**

```
<p:column filterBy="#{equipamento.equipamentoTipoId}" 
          sortBy="#{equipamento.equipamentoTipoId}" 
          headerText="Tipo">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('equipamentoTable').filter()">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" 
                                  itemValue="#{null}" 
                                  noSelectionOption="true">
                    </f:selectItem>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{equipamentoBean.tipos}">
                    </f:selectItems>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{equipamento.equipamentoTipoId}">
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
```

**The error**

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Cant instantiate class: br.com.timbrasil.network.bean.EquipamentoBean.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: br.com.timbrasil.network.bean.EquipamentoBean.
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:1002)
    org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:629)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.calculateFirst(UIData.java:175)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:110)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    br.com.timbrasil.network.bean.EquipamentoBean.<init>(EquipamentoBean.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:1002)
    org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:629)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.calculateFirst(UIData.java:175)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:110)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initial arrayList before add an object;

```
public EquipamentoBean(){
    this.equipamentos = new EquipamentoDao().listaEquipamentos();
    this.tipos = new ArrayList<EquipamentoTipo>();
    for (Equipamento equipamento : equipamentos) {
        this.tipos.add(equipamento.getEquipamentoTipoId());
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO it's a better practice and habit to use a @PostConstruct-method for initializing stuff. The constructor may work here but will fail eventually

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar like a public void init() whit #PostConstruct and add all the content im letting on the constructor?

Comment: Exactly, no concrete problem with the answer but one might as well get a good habit - always use init() with PostConstruct, as the constructor-way will not work when you inject other beans into this one